# IP addresses as x and y labels in a pandas scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'd like to change the x and y labels of a pandas scatter plot. The X axis and Y axis are IP addresses, I am converting them into integers using a simple ip2int function. I'd like to have real "strings" (ie IP addresses) labels at X and Y axis. I tried this, but it does not work well (see screenshot)

```
ipcon['a']=ipcon['srcip'].map(ip2int)
ipcon['b']=ipcon['dstip'].map(ip2int)
ax = ipcon.plot.scatter(x='a',y='b',s=50)
ax.set_xticklabels(ipcon['srcip'])
ax.set_yticklabels(ipcon['dstip'])
ax.set_xlabel("Source IP")
ax.set_ylabel("Destination IP")
```

[screenshot of the resulting scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52yfx.png)

Is there anyway to fix that ? Thanks

**EDIT - WORKING EXAMPLE **

```
import pandas as pd

%pylab inline

ipconn=[["192.168.1.1","192.168.1.2"],["192.168.1.1","192.168.1.2"],["192.168.1.1","192.168.1.3"],["192.168.1.1","192.168.1.99"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(ipconn)

import socket

import struct 


def ip2int(addr):                                                               
    return struct.unpack("!I", socket.inet_aton(addr))[0]                       


def int2ip(addr):                                                               
    return socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("!I", addr)) 

df["x"]=df[0].map(ip2int)
df["y"]=df[1].map(ip2int)
ax = df.plot.scatter(x='x',y='y',s=50)
ax.set_xticklabels(df[0])
ax.set_yticklabels(df[1])
ax.set_xlabel("Source IP")
ax.set_ylabel("Destination IP")
```

**In that example, you can see that the X,Y axis labels are not aligned with the IP values**

The best way, would be to be able to set a function to create the axis label, I think.

Comment: What are you trying to visually gain by graphing source and destination IP addresses in a scatter plot? You'll just end up with a series of vertical dots.

Comment: May you please add some real code in order to be able to reproduce your problem? I mean some input sample in ordet to run your code.

Comment: @cricket_007 in such graph, you will be able to see if a particular host is scanning all the other (vertical line). You will also see "key" server, ie a host who is answering all other host (horizontal line)

Comment: @Fabio I've edited the question and added a working example. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the ticks to values for your labels:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(df[0])
ax.set_yticklabels(df[1])
ax.set_xticks(df["x"])
ax.set_yticks(df["y"])
ax.set_xlabel("Source IP")
ax.set_ylabel("Destination IP")
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working well. I understand now that my initial dataframe is wrong. What I really want to plot is the pd.crosstab of my dataset, with the count, as the size of the dot.

Comment: Good to hear. BTW, you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.